# Sprint Boot - Workday API to get Employee Details

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, workday-api

I would like to get Employee Details from [Workday](https://www.workday.com/) as serve rest API in Spring Boot Application. is there any way we can integrate workday api's in spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics of the API, and taking your question broadly, as long as it is delivered via HTTP you will be able to call it as you would any other.

There is a simple tutorial on leveraging RestTemplate to call API here:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

Once you understand that and want to take things a step further, I highly recommend leveraging OpenFeign, a declarative REST client. The Spring Cloud documentation touches on how to get started with it here:

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html

Comment: Thanks Liam. Let me elaborate what am looking. So in workday we have Employee details such as name, empid, hiring manager name etc.. so i want this information to serve as rest api in spring boot. so for this how would i authenticate workday api so that i can get those details. I hope you got my question.